# Find all M-length sets of positive integers that sum to N

Tags: algorithm

The problem I'm trying to solve is how do we find all the integer sets [a1, a2, ... ,am] so that

```
a1 + a2 + ... + am = N
```

and with the constraint `ai >= 1`

For example if M = 4, and N = 7 there are three answers

```
[1,1,1,4]
[1,1,2,3]
[1,2,2,2]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: This is the problem I was trying to solve - http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=1901

Comment: @HamZa and others, I found a solution that I posted below

Comment: @area5one can it solve the problem posted in the link ?

Comment: @PhamTrung, I think yes if we find all the permutations per set above, and try them against the cabinets (as described in the problem), finding the lowest sum over all partitions

Comment: @area5one It is a little bit over-kill for this problem, I added my solution for the problem in your link below, If you want , you can take a look

Comment: @PhamTrung yea I know, but I started thinking about this as a separate problem and found it interesting by itself .. so the motivation is slightly independent!

Comment: @area5one Ha ha, you're right, nice problem to think about :)

Comment: Are you sure you linked to the correct problem statement? The problem described here appears to be significantly different from the one described in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to print all the sets that sum to N. You can employ a complete search algorithm using recursion. In the following code, M is the number of numbers in the set and N is the sum required.

```
        int M;
        int N;

        void run(){
            M = 4;
            N = 7;
            int[] arr = new int[M];
            print(arr, 0, N, 1);
        }

// req holds the required sum for the numbers in the array from arr[from] 
// to arr[M-1]. 
// "last" holds the last value that we had put in the array.
// The first call to the array will be with last=1.

        void print(int[] arr, int from, int req, int last){

           // Reached the end of the array and sum required 0.

            if(from==M && req==0){
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
                return;
            }



           // Either reached the end of the array but sum is not equal to N
           // Or if we have not reached the end of the array but sum has already 
           // become more than or equal to N.

            if(from==M || req<=0){
                return;
            }



            for(int i=last; i<=req; i++){
                arr[from] = i;
                print(arr, from+1, req-i, i);
            }
        }
```

Output for M=4 and N=7:

```
[1, 1, 1, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Output for M=3 and N=10:

```
[1, 1, 8]
[1, 2, 7]
[1, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 2, 6]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 4]
[3, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the problem in the link, just got accepted.

The idea is simple, assume that we know the maximum value for each section is `X`, and we want to find a way to divide these cabinets to achieve that , we can greedily divide them as follow:

- Starting from first cabinet, iterating through each cabinet, until the total from first to `ith` cabinet is greater than `X`. So this is the first section, similarly, we can select other sections. This greedy will always find a solution (if exists).

Finally, we can using binary search to adjust the value of X, decrease X if we can find a way to divide the cabinets, or increase X if we cannot find one.

Here is the code in Java:

```
public class FairWorkload {

public int getMostWork(int[] folders, int workers) {
    int[] data = new int[folders.length];
    data[0] = folders[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i] = data[i - 1] + folders[i];
    }
    if (workers == 1) {
        return data[data.length - 1];
    }
    int start = 0;
    int end = data[data.length - 1];
    int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while (start <= end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        int index = 0;            
        for (int k = 0; k < workers && index < data.length; k++) {
            int less = index > 0 ? data[index - 1] : 0;
            int temp = index;
            for (int i = index; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i] - less <= mid) {
                    temp = i;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
           // System.out.println(data[temp] - less + " " + mid);
            if(data[temp] - less > mid){
                index = -1;
                break;
            }
            index = temp + 1;

        }
        //System.out.println(mid + " " + index);
        if (index != data.length) {
            start = mid + 1;
        } else {
            result = Math.min(result, mid);
            end = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] data = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1000};
    System.out.println(new FairWorkload().getMostWork(data, 2));
}
}
```

Comment: As an answer to http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=1901 - nice work!

Comment: @Dukeling explanation added :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution uses a counting technique, finding the rightmost term that satisfies `[i] <= [length-1] - 2`, and then flattening out all other terms to the right as much as possible, keeping a[i] <= a[i+1].

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test t = new test();
        t.go();
    }

    private void go() {
        int w = 3;
        int sum = 10;

        int[] terms = new int[w];
        for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
            terms[i] = 1;
        }

        terms[w-1] = sum - w + 1;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(terms));

        for (int i = right_index(terms); i>=0; i = right_index(terms)) {
            terms[i]++;
            int a = terms[i];
            int overflow = -1;

            // balance all the terms to the right
            for (int j = i+1; j < terms.length-1; j++) {
                overflow += terms[j] - a;
                terms[j] = a;
            }

            terms[terms.length-1] += overflow;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(terms));
        }
    }

    // find the rightmost index i, where [i] <= [ia.length-1] - 2
    private int right_index(int[] ia) {

        int max = ia[ia.length-1];

        for (int i = ia.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (ia[i] <= max - 2)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```